# UWP service for accessing SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, uwp, windows-10-universal

RE: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec

I'm hoping to clarify some points and concerns. When designing UWP for Windows 10 Microsoft, in my own thoughts, short-sightedly left SYSTEM.DATA out of the framework. This means that you must use a WCF web service as a middle man to access any data from SQL Server and return it to your application. Here's where I get confused:

1. When the app is run from Visual Studio and then stopped, the web service is still running in the background and can be accessed from any browser. You could easily find the address by using something like fiddler.

   This concerns me for because anyone can then see your service and use it and I'm not sure how to obfuscate the service itself.
2. I'm also not sure how the service itself gets bundled and deployed. When creating the service reference, you reference a specific address and port. Does it always use that same port no matter where it's installed? Does the store app automatically deploy the web service as part of the UWP download/install?

Overall, I'm skeptical of the decision they made to exclude system.data and the ability to protect IP or secure your application when you can simply browse to the service address and review the function calls, profile, or decompile.

I hope I've been clear on my concerns and that some kind soul can entertain them.

Comment: What exactly is the question, or is it primarily intended to be feedback on the missing API? The lack of System.Data.* APIs is a feature gap that is tracked on our UserVoice forum. It is planned to get addressed with the upcoming support for NET Standard 2.0 in UWP (as announced at BUILD 2017 this year). Also you can access the System.Data.* APIs from your UWP today via a Desktop Bridge extension. See my BUILD talk: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8012 and the corresponding sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLServer

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I'll watch your channel9 video and review the sample code. Thanks again!

Comment: Desktop bridge is not going to work for me but the NET Standard 2.0 is great news and I'm excited for it. Thank you for the info and I'll be looking forward to the Fall Update.

Comment: Just curious: why would desktop bridge not work for your scenario?

Comment: It's a free SQL health check for the masses. I would want everything contained in a single download from the App store. My understanding is that the bridge would need to be installed separately. Right now I'm using a desktop app and hosting on dropbox. Have been waiting for a long time to push this to the store.

Comment: Daniel, your understanding is not correct. The Desktop Bridge allows you to package, deploy and service all components in a single package that can be downloaded from the Windows Store. Check out this blog post that has a sample you can download from the Store that is doing conceptually the same thing: https://stefanwick.com/2017/05/26/uwp-calling-office-interop-apis/  - also you might want to watch this video for more info: https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Connect/2016/198

Comment: I don't have an installer for my WinForms app. It's just a zip. Is there a step-by-step starting with level 0? lol

Comment: No need to have an installer. ZIP is fine to get on the Desktop Bridge. I'll connect with you offline for next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service is a separate application that you typically deploy to some remote machine, for example in the cloud.

Your UWP client app connects to this service over the Internet but the service is not packaged and deployed together with your client application. It may serve several different kind of client applications simultaneously.

The client application obviously needs to know the address of the service to be able to connect to it at runtime.

So you basically create two different applications. One service application that reads from and writes to the database and one UWP client application that consumes the remote service application. The service application may be deployed to Azure and the UWP application to the Windows Store.

Comment: Thank you, This helps clear up my understanding. My intent is not to create a database in the cloud but to connect to the client's SQL Server via whatever server name they type in so it would appear that this is dead until SYSTEM.DATA is added or perhaps it can be done with Stefan's info that I'll look into shortly.